Facing issue in Cognito google sign in next js
I'm implementing Amplify google sign in Next js 14, using aws-amplify v6. I'm getting 307 code status for authentication code call



Following is my code:
app/layout.tsx
import "./page.css";

import { Metadata } from "next";

import ConfigureAmplifyClientSide from "@/components/auth";
import Header from "@/components/header";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "My Page Title",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <ConfigureAmplifyClientSide>
          <Header />
          {children}
        </ConfigureAmplifyClientSide>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


app/components/auth/page.tsx
"use client";
import "aws-amplify/auth/enable-oauth-listener";

import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import { useEffect } from "react";

import { amplifyConfig } from "../../config/amplify";

export default function ConfigureAmplifyClientSide({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    Amplify.configure(amplifyConfig, { ssr: true });
  }, []);
  return <>{children}</>;
}


app/api/auth/login/page.tsx
export default function Login() {
  return (
    <div
      className="bg-no-repeat h-dvh w-full  bg-center bg-cover flex items-center justify-center absolute"
      style={{ backgroundImage: "url('/public/images/login_bg.png')" }}
    >
      <Image src={loginBackground} alt="logo" fill={true} objectFit="cover" />
      <div className="w-[33rem] h-[17.8125rem] flex flex-col justify-center items-center bg-white opacity-80 shadow rounded">
        <Image
          className="pt-[0.6rem] mt-[-0.4rem] h-13 w-[10.25rem]"
          src={logo}
          alt="logo"
          width={150}
          height={150}
        />
        <p className="mt-1 text-xl font-medium">NextJs POC</p>
        <button
          className="relative bg-blue-500 text-white border-1 border-solid border-blue-500 mt-14 flex justify-center items-center h-12 rounded w-72 px-3 py-4"
          onClick={async () => {
            await signInWithRedirect({ provider: "Google" });
          }}
          title={`Sign in with Google`}
        >
          <Image
            className="h-full box-border w-auto absolute left-0 top-0 p-3 border-2 border-solid border-blue-500 bg-white rounded"
            src={googleLogo}
            alt="Picture of the author"
            width={50}
            height={50}
          />
          <span className="text-center">Sign in with Google</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

app/middleware.ts
import { fetchAuthSession } from "aws-amplify/auth/server";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

import { runWithAmplifyServerContext } from "@/utils/amplifyServerUtils";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const response = NextResponse.next();

  const authenticated = await runWithAmplifyServerContext({
    nextServerContext: { request, response },
    operation: async (contextSpec) => {
      try {
        const session = await fetchAuthSession(contextSpec);
        return session.tokens !== undefined;
      } catch (error) {
        return false;
      }
    },
  });

  if (authenticated) {
    if (request.nextUrl.pathname.includes("/login")) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", request.url));
    }
    return response;
  } else {
    if (request.nextUrl.pathname.includes("/login")) {
      return NextResponse.next();
    }
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL(
        `/api/auth/login?callbackUrl=${encodeURIComponent(
          request.nextUrl.pathname
        )}`,
        request.nextUrl.pathname !== "/"
          ? request.url.split(request.nextUrl.pathname)[0]
          : request.url
      )
    );
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)"],
};

app/utils/amplifyServerUtils.ts
import { createServerRunner } from "@aws-amplify/adapter-nextjs";
import { amplifyConfig } from "../config/amplify";

export const { runWithAmplifyServerContext } = createServerRunner({
  config: amplifyConfig,
});


app/config/amplify.ts
import { AuthConfig } from "@aws-amplify/core";
import { ResourcesConfig } from "aws-amplify";

// eslint-disable-next-line
export const aws_project_region =
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AMPLIFY_PROJECT_REGION ?? "eu-west-1";

export const amplifyConfig: ResourcesConfig = {
  Auth: {
    Cognito: {
      identityPoolId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AMPLIFY_AUTH_IDENTITY_POOL_ID!,
      userPoolId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AMPLIFY_AUTH_USER_POOL_ID!,
      userPoolClientId:
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AMPLIFY_AUTH_USER_POOL_WEB_CLIENT_ID!,
      loginWith: {
        oauth: {
          domain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AMPLIFY_OAUTH_DOMAIN!,
          scopes: [
            "openid",
            "email",
            "profile",
            "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin",
          ],
          redirectSignIn: [
            process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AMPLIFY_OAUTH_REDIRECT_SIGN_IN!,
          ],
          redirectSignOut: [
            process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AMPLIFY_OAUTH_REDIRECT_SIGN_OUT!,
          ],
          responseType: "code",
        },
        // username: true,
      },
    },
  }
};


I tried check the amplify documentation. Searching for the specify error. Also refered multiple number of blogs.
Im expecting I perform successful login into the app.
